# Write result of Python Script to txt file

Tags: python, regex

I have the following script in Python that is meant to find words with two or more vowels in them and output the result to a txt file. The script currently runs, but the output file is empty. I have tried several different methods to no avail, any idea why the output file is blank? I am using the (re) import to treat the input as a regular expression.

```
#!C:\Python33\python.exe

import re

file = open("Text of Steve Jobs' Commencement address (2005).htm");
output = open('twoVoweledWordList.txt', 'w');

for word in file.read():
   if len(re.findall('[aeiouy]', word)) >= 2:
      match == True;
      while True :
        output.write(word, '\n');

        file.close()
        output.close()
```

Comment: file.read() reads one character at a time and you are looking it up for two vowels.

Comment: the while True will cause an infinite loop. Watch out!

Comment: That makes sense! What would be a better way to read each word in at a time?

Comment: `match == True` is a comparison, not an assignment.  Also, in Python you don't need a semicolon on the end of any line.

Comment: @steveha thanks, I am new to Python and used to Java syntax old habits die hard.

Comment: I didnt know that `y` is a vowel. :(

Comment: `while True :` should be `if match:` I guess

Comment: There is no need to loop or set a `match` flag or anything else like that. `if len(re.findall('[aeiouy]', word)) >= 2` is already exactly the condition under which we want to write the `word` to the output file, and we want to write that given `word` exactly once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked for a better way to read a word at a time.  Here you go:

```
with open(input_file_name, "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            # do something with each word here
```

Comments:

- In general I try to avoid using built-in Python features as variable names.  Since `file` is a built-in in Python 2.x, syntax-coloring text editors will flag it in a different color... might as well just use `f` for the variable name.
- It's best to use the `with` statement.  It is very clear, and in all versions of Python it makes sure your file is properly closed when you are done.  (Here it won't matter, but it's really a best practice.)
- `open()` returns an object that you can use in a `for` loop.  You will get one line of input from the file at a time.
- `line.split()` splits the line into words, using any "white space" (spaces, tabs, etc.)

I don't know if you have seen generator functions yet, but you can wrap up the above doubly-nested `for` loops into a generator function like this:

```
def words(f):
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

with open(input_file_name, "rt") as f:
    for word in words(f):
        # do something with word
```

I like hiding the machinery like this.  And if you ever needed to make the word-splitting more complicated, the complex part is nicely separated from the part that actually handles the words.

Comment: I implemented the function as you listed above and my output is the entire html file. I am using `if len(re.findall('aeiou]', word)) >= 2` `output.write(word + '\n' `

Comment: Double-check your regex :)

Comment: Found out the issue, it wasn't overwriting the old file :) Less of a code issue more of a dumb human one, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `with` statement you dont have to worry about closing the file explicitly. And `y` is not a vowel, I believe. So, I removed it from my answer.

```
import re

with open("Input.txt") as inputFile, open("Output.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in inputFile:
        for word in line.split():
            if len(re.findall('[aeiou]', word)) >= 2:
                output.write(word + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

While steveha says it nicely, just in case you like for loops better :-

```
import re

file = open("Text of Steve Jobs' Commencement address (2005).htm")
output = open('twoVoweledWordList.txt', 'w')

for line in file:
    for word in line.split():
       if len(re.findall('[aeiouy]', word)) >= 2:
          output.write(word + '\n')
```

Comment: I recommend re-writing the first `for` loop as simply: `for line in file:`  The `file.readlines()` method function will read the entire file into memory, but we only need one line at a time.  Simply using the opened file object as an iterator will read one line at a time.  This won't matter much for small files, but what if the file was 10 GB of data?  Then it would matter a lot.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is best done the way in your answer. I just put it as an alternative and because I had written it all up :p